# Why I got an "400 Bad Request" error from Express when there are some Chinese words urlencoded to the utf-8 form?

Tags: node.js, express, urlencode

I am using **Express 4.x** to developing my blog system.
When I visit the url like "localhost:3000/u/rxy/2015-1-16/[转载]第三篇文章", it is all right.But when I visit the url like "localhost:3000/u/rxy/2015-1-16/%5Bl%7D%5D,%DB%C7%87%E0", I got an "400 Bad Request" error.

```
Error: Bad Request
at SendStream.error (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:239:16)
at SendStream.pipe (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:411:32)
at serveStatic (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:110:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:13)
at /home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:238:9
at Function.proto.process_params (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:313:12)
at /home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:229:12
at Function.match_layer (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:296:3)
at next (/home/aside99/workspace/blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:190:10)
```

**The flowing picture is the way I used to redirect url.**

```
   var url = '/u/' + post.name + '/' + post.time.day + '/' + post.t    itle;
   console.log('reprint:url:', url);
   res.redirect(url);
```

**And I have consoled the url.**

```
reprint:url: /u/rxy/2015-1-16/[转载]第四篇文章
```

I don't know why it is .

Comment: double check your URI encode.  "%5Bl" looks suspicious

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

You are getting above error because you are using **%** in **path param**.

Try Using Query Param (eg localhost:3000/u/rxy/2015-1-16?blogId=%5Bl%7D%5D,%DB%C7%87%E0") instead of Path Param (localhost:3000/u/rxy/2015-1-16/%5Bl%7D%5D,%DB%C7%87%E0). Or remove % from the Path Param.